# Animation with an Object appearing and Disappearing using Boolean Modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers, unity

I'm working on creating an animation involving the boolean modifier in Blender as show below. I'm happy with how the animation looks in Blender, but when I try to export the animation to Unity, it doesn't work the way I intended.

[image: Animation in Blender]

[image: Animation in Unity]

I created the animation by moving the arrow's location on the x axis, using an array modifier to create a total of 3 arrows, and using a boolean modifier set to intersect to only display the arrows between two planes.

I've determined that the problem is that the boolean modifier is applied at frame 1 in the exported animation, which means that the two visible arrows just move as shown in the second gif.

Does anyone have advice on how to handle this situation?

Comment: Seeing as your animation is barely longer than 20 frames, you could export 20 different models and in unity create a prefab which animates their visibility.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541

Comment: @Leander This is better than anything I've come up with, but I was hoping for a solution that could work for longer animations in the future, too.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos My question had nothing to do with materials. Is there a part of that answer that I missed?

Comment: I think Duarte misunderstood. For longer animations, Im guessing you will have to implement the boolean operation in unity. Looks like someone has managed to do so [for the editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSNadFy9W_0). There is no way Blender C coded boolean modifier will be ported in an fbx.

Comment: There is, see part "*[Same applies for many other features specific to applications](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541)* (...)"